# Ramda JS: How to perform a map where I call R.replace for a given property on each object?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

Given the following data:

```
const my_data = [
  {
    name: "John",
    age: 22
  },
  {
    name: "Johnny",
    age: 15
  },
  {
    name: "Dave",
    age: 27
  }
]
```

I want to transform the data such that the substring "John" is replaced with "Ben" in each of the name properties so it looks like this:

```
[
  {
    name: "Ben",
    age: 22
  },
  {
    name: "Benny",
    age: 15
  },
  {
    name: "Dave",
    age: 27
  }
]
```

I want to do so in the proper functional way (I think is points-free but I am still learning), so I can reuse this in a pipeline, say first reducing by age and then doing the replace, or doing the replace first then doing a sort.  How would I do this using the Ramda functions?

```
var fix_names = ???
var fixed_data = R.map( fix_names, my_data );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
R.map(R.over(R.lensProp('name'), R.replace('John', 'Ben')))(my_data)
```

See [`R.over`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#over) and [`R.lensProp`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#lensProp).

Comment: `R.evolve` can be used here also: `R.map(R.evolve({name: R.replace('John', 'Ben')})`

Comment: R.over (and R.evolve) is what I needed to look at.  I was trying to solve the problem with just R.set.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason to prefer point-free functions. Readability is what really matters:

```js
var myData = [ new Person("John",   22)
             , new Person("Johnny", 15)
             , new Person("Dave",   27)
             ];

var fixedData = myData.map(fixName);

alert(JSON.stringify(fixedData, null, 4));

function fixName(person) {
    return Object.assign(new Person, person, {
        name: person.name.replace(/John/g, "Ben")
    });
}

function Person(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age  = age;
}
```

Point-free functions are useful in very limited cases like [eta conversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#.CE.B7-conversion) and [function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition). Point-free functions should not be treated as the cornerstone of functional programming.

Comment: What if I'll add more properties on `Person`? Adding each property to all of such methods isn't the best solution

Comment: You can always copy all the properties onto the new object using a loop. What do you think the `lensProp` function of Ramda does? It manually copies each property using a loop. In fact, copying properties is such a common operation that a native function has been added for the sole purpose of copying properties of several objects. The [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) function can be used to copy properties from source objects onto a single target object automatically. I've updated my answer to reflect the change.

Comment: Sure, I understand what happens in `lensProp`. Just wanted your code to be more like davidchambers' example. I disagree that  davidchambers' code "requires a lot of mental juggling". If you know the basics of currying and lensed and have used Ramda for a while, then this code is pretty straightforward. And look, how naturally it converts to more composable, maintainable and still simple code in Ramda:  https://gist.github.com/iofjuupasli/dc251f17030d88603e71f86f3265c19d

Comment: As one of the creators of Ramda I [do stress](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1243641+points-free) that points-free is not a panacea.  But why do you balk at lenses and still buy into `map`?  Wouldn't a `for`-loop be more explicit still?  And how about `Object.assign`?  Why did you switch to that?  It's not as obvious what's going on when you use it.  Of course these are rhetorical questions.  The answer is obvious.  These are useful abstractions.  Lenses provide another useful abstraction, as does the `evolve` function iofjuupasli mentioned below.

Comment: To me the most readable answer provided so far is iofjuupasli's `R.map(R.evolve({name: R.replace('John', 'Ben')})` followed closely by davidchambers's `R.map(R.over(R.lensProp('name'), R.replace('John', 'Ben'))`.  Neither version of this answer even comes close to capturing the essence of the problem.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I don't balk at lenses. In fact, I love lenses in Haskell when programming in the `State` monad. However, JavaScript is not Haskell and lenses in JavaScript don't make much sense. Lenses solve a problem in Haskell which is a non-problem in JavaScript. Also, do note that you are not the only person reading your own code. A lot of JavaScript programmers are not functional programmers and for a lot of people lenses are a novel concept. Finally, the main point I was debating is the need for everything to be written in pointfree style. That is absolutely unnecessary. Readability counts

Comment: @iofjuupasli I updated my answer to address the problems you raised.

Comment: @procrastinator: From the original question: "I want to do so in the proper functional way (I think is points-free but I am still learning), so I can reuse this in a pipeline, say first reducing by age and then doing the replace, or doing the replace first then doing a sort. **How would I do this using the Ramda functions?**" (Emphasis added). Of course Ramda is not an essential tool. We wrote it because we wanted tools to help us write in a certain manner -- including not having to write any more `for` loops!  If you're happy with what's built into the language, it's entirely superfluous.

Comment: @AaditMShah: 'Really? In your opinion what's the "essence of the problem"?'  Replace "John" with "Ben" in each of the "name" properties, as described in the question.  `evolve` is about updating named properties.  `replace` is about replacing text, and `map` is about applying something to every element of a list/container.  Granted, one has to know this.  But for your solution, one has to know about `String.prototype.replace`, constructor functions (for heaven's sake, why?), `Object.assign`, and `Array.prototype.map`.  `evolve` is an abstractions that helps with real problems.

Comment: @AaditMShah: Do you have any demonstration that currying is slow?  Ramda has a few issues with speed, but as far as I know, those all have to do with insisting on value equality rather than reference equality, and not to do with currying.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Ramda also requires people to know about `String.prototype.replace` because `R.replace` is just a wrapper around it. Constructor functions are not a part of the solution. Read the answer again. Also, for heaven's sake why would people have a problem with constructor functions? `R.evolve` is just as complex to understand, if not more, than `Object.assign` because of first-class functions. Finally, `R.map` is the same as `Array.prototype.map`. My answer does capture the "essence of the problem" according to your own note, 'replace "John" with "Ben" in each of the "name" properties'.

Comment: @AaditMShah: Given how much we've agreed in the past, I'm surprised how fundamental our disagreement is here. Yes, `evolve` is an abstraction, but to my mind it's the _right_ abstraction. (Lenses are almost as good, but `evolve` is the best.) It's designed to create a new object by cloning an existing one, except that it applies transformations to specified properties. That's much closer to our goal than `Object.assign` which is designed to merge the properties of a collection of objects into one. It's the same reason that `map` is better than `for` even though it's a more complex abstraction.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I'm not saying that it's the wrong abstraction. I'm not even against abstractions. I'm just saying that not everything should be written in pointfree style because it's not always more readable. For example a simple pointful function like `\x y -> x * x + y * y` can be written in Haskell as ``(+) `on` join (*)``. That's all I was trying to say. The reason I wanted to say this is because a lot of people beginning with Ramda feel like everything should be written in pointfree style because they equate pointfree with functional. I just wanted to disassociate pointfree from functional

Comment: @ScottSauyet That being said, I'm sorry for being so quarrelsome. It was unbecoming of me. I'll edit my answer and remove all the argumentative parts.

Comment: @ScottSauyet BTW, the reason I wrote this answer was because the OP said "I want to do so in the proper functional way (I think is points-free but I am still learning)". The OP clearly thinks that "the proper functional way" is to use point-free functions. I just wanted to tell the OP to concentrate on readability rather than on trying to make everything point-free. If premature optimization is the root of all evil then premature conversion into pointfree style is the root of all unreadability.